Cannot disable dynamic dependencies in rpmbuild?
I need to rebuild one pre-built RPM package, change location of .service file in it.
Pretty straight-forward:

unpack source package:
rpm2cpio "$srcrpm" | ( cd "$src" ; cpio --no-absolute-filenames -idmv)

generate SPEC file:
rpmrebuild -s "$spec" -p "$srcrpm"

make changes to it:
sed -i 's/\/etc\/systemd\/system/\/usr\/lib\/systemd\/system/' "$spec"

and build it:
rpmbuild -bb -vvv --define "_topdir $dstdir" --buildroot "$src" "$spec"


It all runs ok, BUT: original RPM does not have any Requires, while newly generated RPM does have:
$ rpm -q --requires -p "$srcrpm" 
$ rpm -q --requires -p "$dstrpm"
/bin/sh
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1

Those dependencies prevent new RPM from being installed on RHEL7 systems, while original RPM is installed on RHEL7 without any problem. (The rebuild is done on RHEL9 system).
Tried all the following:

added rpmbuild --nodeps
added to SPEC file:

AutoReq: no
AutoProv: no
AutoReqProv: no
%global __requires_exclude ^.*$
%global __requires_exclude_from ^.*$
%define __requires ${nil}


edited /usr/lib/rpm/find-requires, commented rpmdeps out of it

Bad luck, still Requires exist in new RPM. Why? What else am I missing?

yum install mock
mock -r centos-7-x86_64 foo.src.rpm

You may want to add yourself to mock group to avoid entering password each time you run it: https://rpm-software-management.github.io/mock/#setup
